# What are the rules to this dice game?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

Does anyone know the rules to this dice game? It has 7 dices with:

0-5

1-6

2-7

1-3

7-12

plus and minus

divide and multiply

[image]

Answer (score 5):

They appear to be an assortment of ["math numbers"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou5Ol.jpg) and ["math operators"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0dxK.jpg) dice from [Koplow Games](https://koplow.ecadv.com/website/). While they could be used for a game, they are sold as learning aids ("educational resources").